# calculate R,X,R0 and X0 using Fault MVA Input

Tags: python, math

I am writing a script in python to calculate `R`, `X`, `R0` and `X0` but I am finding an error. Please suggest me right script.

Also, is it possible to make input data as a variable like when we run this script? It should pop-up and ask enter these input data. Here's the code:

```
import sys,math

Vp = 115
3phF_MVA = 558
XR_Ratio = 8.7
Z=(VpVp/3phF_MVA)
R=Z/m.sqrt(1+XR_Ratio*XR_Ratio)
X=XR_Ratio*R
```

Answer (score 0):

A variable name cannot begin with a number in Python. Therefore, I presume the error you're getting is a `SyntaxError`. You need to rename `3phF_MVA`.

In addition, `m.sqrt` should raise a `NameError` as well, because `m` is not defined. You probably refer to `math.sqrt` instead; you need to correct this as well.

Now if you want to take the values as a user input, you need to call the `input` built-in. Be careful, you need to convert the result, either to a `float` or an `int`:

```
Vp = int(input("Vp: "))
XR_Ratio = float(input("XR_Ratio: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ask the user for input data use :

Var = raw_input("VAR : ")
This function will display "VAR : " in the python console. The user can then write the value to use for this variable.

Be careful that all inputs will be of type String.

For your example, this should do it :

```
print "Enter the values for each variable : "
ValuesGiven = False
while(ValuesGiven == False):
    VP = raw_input("Vp : ")
    phF_MVA = raw_input("phF_MVA : ")
    XR_Ratio = raw_input("XR_Ratio : ")
    try:
        VP=float(VP)
        phF_MVA = float(phF_MVA)
        XR_Ratio = float(XR_Ratio)
        ValuesGiven = True
    except ValueError:
        print "Wrong Input, try again"
```

Your question is not indented, so I am not sure this is what you are looking for, but for your calculation it should be :

```
import numpy as np

Z=VP*VP/phF_MVA
R=Z/np.sqrt(1+XR_Ratio*XR_Ratio)
X=XR_Ratio*R
```

Hope it'll do it.

Comment: Thanks. I am able to give input but could not calculate Z and R value using above said syntax

Comment: If you just took the code as it is, you probably raise a NameError

Just change variable Vp into VP :


    import numpy as np


    Z=VP*VP/phF_MVA

    R=Z/np.sqrt(1+XR_Ratio*XR_Ratio)

    X=XR_Ratio*R

Comment: Happy I helped. You can mark the question as answered